# I tried this code in mysql but it was row operation,how to insert column wise data

Tags: mysql

MySQL stored procedures can be used to split the string, the following details for your usage of MySQL stored procedures, for your reference learning purposes.

Existing string, such as Apple, banana, orange, pears, grape, it should follow the comma (,) is divided into:

apple 
banana 
orange 
pears 
grape
Where in () method can then query.

1, the specific function:

## Function: func_split_TotalLength the

```
DELIMITER $ $
 DROP   function IF EXISTS `func_split_TotalLength` $ $
 CREATE DEFINER = `root` @ `%` FUNCTION `func_split_TotalLength`
 (F_string varchar (1000), f_delimiter varchar (5)) RETURNS   int (11)
  BEGIN  
 return 1 + (length (f_string) - length (replace (f_string, f_delimiter,'')));
 END $ $
 DELIMITER;
```

## Function: func_split

```
    DELIMITER $ $
    DROP   function IF EXISTS `func_split` $ $
    CREATE DEFINER = `root` @ `%` FUNCTION `func_split`
    (F_string varchar (1000), f_delimiter varchar (5), f_order int) RETURNS   varchar        (255) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN  
    declare result varchar (255) default   '';
     set result = reverse (substring_index (reverse (substring_index (f_string, f_delimiter, f_order)), f_delimiter, 1));
     return result;
    END $ $
   DELIMITER;
```

## Stored procedure: SplitString

```
  DELIMITER $ $
  DROP   PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `splitString` $ $
  CREATE   Procedure the `SplitString`
  (IN f_string varchar (1000), IN f_delimiter varchar (5))
  BEGIN  
  declare cnt int   default 0;
  declare i int   default 0;
  set cnt = func_split_TotalLength (f_string, f_delimiter);
  DROP   TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_split`;
  create   temporary   table `tmp_split` (`status` varchar (128) not   null) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
 while i <cnt
 do
 set i = i + 1;
 insert   into tmp_split (`status`) values ??(func_split (f_string, f_delimiter, i));
end while;
 END $ $
 DELIMITER;
```

2, the test will be successful segmentation

```
 call splitString ("apple, banana, orange, pears, grape", ",");
 select * from tmp_split;
 The results are splitting success:
```

mysql> call splitString ("apple, banana, orange, pears, grape", ","); 
      select * from tmp_split; 
      Query OK, 1 row affected but i need to insert by column wise data...,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would use an other approach to this problem, to get the result in table form:

## Simpler approach without a stored procedure

Assuming you have a table example with two columns: id and col1 like so:

CREATE TABLE example (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 VARCHAR(1000)
);

and those values

```
id | col
-----------------------------
 1 | abcd,efgh,ijkl,ghjy,sdfg
 2 | some other text
```

and you want to get the comma separated values from col into a column with one value at the time for the id = 1. Then I would use following sql:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.col, ',', t.n), ',', -1) value
FROM example e CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
    ORDER BY n
) t
WHERE 
    e.id = 1
AND
    t.n <= (1 + LENGTH(e.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(e.col, ',', '')));
```

It's the same procedure as in the stored procedure. You can use this result easily in joins or other operations.

See this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74c4e/1)

---

First part assuming, a stored procedure was needed.

**stored procedure**

- no other function needed
- no explicit temp table
- works up to 1000 items, easily exptensible

Code:

```
DROP procedure splitString;
DELIMITER $ $
CREATE procedure splitString(IN f_string VARCHAR(1000), IN f_delimiter VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.haystack, f_delimiter, t.n
           ), f_delimiter, -1) as value 
    FROM (SELECT f_string as haystack) h
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
           ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
           ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
        ORDER BY n
    ) t
    WHERE t.n <= 
    (
        1 
        + (
            CHAR_LENGTH(f_string) 
            - 
            CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(f_string, f_delimiter, ''))
          ) 
          / CHAR_LENGTH(f_delimiter)
    );
END;
$ $
DELIMITER ;
```

## Explanation

**1. Generating a list of numbers from 1 to 1000**

The most inner SELECT

```
SELECT 
    1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
ORDER BY n
```

does not more than creating a list with the numbers from 1 to 1000. If you need more then you should see, how it's done. Add a line with those `union all` and call this `d`, add + d.N * 1000 to the sum.

**2. Performing the split and getting just one element per row**

We use this list to do the split of your func_split in the form of (a bit more readable statements)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.haystack, f_delimiter, 1
       ), f_delimiter, -1) as value 
FROM (SELECT f_string as haystack) h

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.haystack, f_delimiter, 2
       ), f_delimiter, -1) as value 
FROM (SELECT f_string as haystack) h

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.haystack, f_delimiter, 3
       ), f_delimiter, -1) as value 
FROM (SELECT f_string as haystack) h
```

that extract the first, second, third, ... substring, separated with the f_delimiter.

**Getting the number of elements**

Our WHERE clause is all but self-explanatory:

```
-- because we begin by 1 we've got to include the upper limit
WHERE t.n <= 
(
    1  -- we have one comma less than parts
    + (
        -- count how many characters (not bytes) we lose by the replace operation
        CHAR_LENGTH(f_string) 
        - 
        CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(f_string, f_delimiter, ''))
      ) 
      -- and divide this by the count of characters in the delimiter string
      / CHAR_LENGTH(f_delimiter)
);
```

**Note**

LENGTH() instead of CHAR_LENGTH() would do too, because the result of the division would be the same, but I like to do it right :-)

** Check of function**

You can check the result with

```
CALL splitString('apple, bananas, grape, ananas, pears', ', ');
```

it returns

```
value
-----
apple
bananas
grape
ananas
pears
```

Comment: thank you so much Vmai..,but what requirement is my input like big string in single col 'agadjgh,ajdjg,jadgjgd,hjdhjah,hkk,,,kdk,' i need to separate this delimit by ',' and insert into table 2 with separate cols..can you plz help me...

Comment: The first input value is the list of values separated by the separator in the second input value. Please note, that an value of the list can't contain the separator. I. e. if the separator is the comma, no value can contain a comma.

Comment: You can feed this procedure i.e. with a comma separated list of integers: CALL splitString('1,2,3,4,5', ',') and the output will be a column with the values from 1 to 5 as values.

Comment: table 1 contains--->"abcd,efgh,ijkl,ghjy,sdfg" in single col..i need to separate this string into table 2---> c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 datas

Comment: If this string is element of a table, I wouldn't use this procedure at all, I would use a statement similar to the select on the inside. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: i tried this code separating string into col substring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223361/how-reduce-this-code-in-mysql-for-separate-a-given-string please check code sir..,

Comment: Have a look at the new answer (at the start of the answer) and the demo. I think you want that.

Comment: you please resolve my problem can check this link                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223361/how-reduce-this-code-in-mysql-for-separate-a-given-string

Comment: Before I forget it: Especially in combination with INSERT INTO ... SELECT <this expression> is my approach much faster than agonizing row by row insert.